# Best way to move image from iPhone, edit it and move editted image back to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, file-transfer

I'm quite new to iOS and iPhone and I'm having troubles to find a good and easy solution for the following task.

1. As I'm used to take pictures in RAW only with my DSLR, I use Apple ProRAW file format on my iPhone.
2. I convert the image to 16BIT PNG via Darkroom (the reason is that Darktable is not able to read the file directly). The RAW file and PNG file are than also Backedup.
3. I edit the image and save it as JPG.
4. Delete the RAW image on the iPhone.
5. Upload the edited (and smaler) image via iTunes to the iPhone.

Is there any other/better way to perform the tasks? I use Windows on my Laptop and Linux on my PC, so I'm open for solutions in both worlds...

Hope someone has ideas and can help me :-)

Thanks for your hints
Alex